# Suppose we fill a membrane with ferro fluid, and alter the magnetic field around it in specific ways, what dynamics can come into play?

Tags: experimental-physics, biophysics

im trying to develop a flexible robotic arm filled with ferro fluid. Different flexible motions can be performed using this concept.